# How can I slow down the motors of my magnetic stirrer?

Tags: motor, control, pid-controller, hacking

I have a 5-motor magnetic stirrer, used for non-contact stirring of labware. My problem is that this stirrer was designed for bacterial cell culture, and not mammalian (more fragile, needs slower mixing), which is what I need it for. Without spending $2000 on a new one (yes, pharmaceutical companies are really that dumb) is it possible to make the motors spin slower?

I have opened it up and had a poke around.
Here is the main board:

[image: top]

and

[image: bottom]

There is a potentiometer beneath, which was originally used for speed control. Picture of the bottom tray:

[image: Here]

It appears as though the motors are PID controlled, as when I held one and stopped it spinning, it sped up over the target rpm and then slowed down again. My theory was that the PID setpoint was given by the potentiometer somehow, and then the controller varies the voltage to achieve the correct speed.

One option I was considering was snipping off all of the motors and connecting them to a variable voltage lab power supply, and just using that to change the RPM, however we would ideally want to be able to change the setpoint of the PID, and aim for a specific RPM. this is so we can keep it the same when mixing fluids of varying viscosities.

The second idea was to swap out the potentiometer with one of a different range, so that it could provide a different setpoint to the controller (if that even is what is happening here). I tried measuring the resistance over the potentiometer with a multimeter on varying positions of rotating the dial, but that didn't seem to change much.

Comment: Please provide schematics and pictures of the motor's markings.

Comment: There's definitely a control loop - the motors are controlled via PWM through the SOIC-8 MOSFETs next to them, the speed is measured via hall sensors under each motor (using the stirrer magnets), and the PIC microcontrollers implement the control scheme. Check if the potentiometer is connected to the PICs. If yes, check the input voltage range to the PICs as you turn the potentiometer.

Comment: So the potentiometer controls the speed, but the slowest speed is still too fast? or what?

Comment: try measuring the resistance while the potentiometer isn't connected to the circuit. I guess you know how a potentiometer works, but in case not, note that only the middle leg changes resistance (and they might have wired it so it's not the middle)

Comment: The ICs "beneath the discs"(IC 1,2,3, 8,9,10, 17,18,19) seem to be some kind of position/motion sensors. Can you pry off one of the magnet holders and share what the other side of the discs looks like? If there are black segments on white, half their angle and double their count.

Comment: (If indeed those ICs are hall effect sensors, attach four more tiny, flat magnets to the (soft magnetic?) disks, poles alternating. This gives three times the signals compared to the original configuration (2 ferrite magnets?!).) (I can't see tinkering with different potentiometer values, different voltages to the potentiometer, swapping motors or adding resistors in series with them getting you anywhere.)

Comment: @user253751 Yes, exactly, and thanks for the tip, will try measuring again.

Comment: If the slowest speed is still too fast, most likely this is nothing to do with the potentiometer, but the software running on the microcontroller. They don't make a minimum speed by adding extra resistance in series with the pot - they make it by making the software go at that speed when the pot is at its minimum resistance.

Comment: @user253751 aha, that is a very salient point. I think I'll try what greybeard is suggesting.

Comment: @greybeard Yes, there are black marks underneath the white spinning discs. You are suggesting to increase the number of them and decreasing the space between them? What kind of material is it (if it's important), can I just put some black tape on instead? they are pretty dense already, with only 3-4mm between each one at the edge. Each black mark is about 3mm wide.

Comment: by the way, I wonder whether it is easier to put together your own stirrer with an Arduino as the PID controller, than to hack this one to make it work - because when you make your own thing you know how it works and don't have to guess or reverse-engineer. As you said you can just power the motors from a variable voltage but you want the feedback

Comment: If you want to continue to use the closed loop (I assumed so above), you got to convince the controller the discs/magnets are spinning faster than they actually are. As everything *you* don't put in your question is (best case: informed) guesswork, I suggest the material is cardboard. I'd use a laser printer to print a similar pattern with about twice as many black&white segments at the sensor's radius on stiff paper/a self adhesive etiquette and replace the disc or stick the etiquette to it. 3mm may actually be close to the resolution achievable - in that case, solutions may grow awkward.

Comment: (Without a closed loop, the "problem" is dead simple (and the solution lacking, if nothing else, sophistication), the hardest part being choosing rotation directions.)

Comment: (I keep pondering turning the stirrers into rotors of motors where the stator is three (pairs of?) coils on the board - "solid state".)